# Are questions about [at-command]s on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

**A little introduction.** [AT commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) are the language "spoken" by modems. They are just a set of commands made up of ASCII characters starting with `AT` and closed by `\r`, each performing a specific action (either setting internal parameters or starting actual actions). All these characters are sent to the modem though a serial interface (for example, USB or [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)) from an host processor: it might be a PC or an embedded microcontroller. There's often a program managing it.

---

I admit [[at-command]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-command) is a *niche tag*. Nevertheless, it is relevant for programmers having to deal with modems while writing their host applications that, for some reason, need to send data through a cellular device. Here it is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851316/11336762) of a high scored answer in this tag.

However, often happens that OPs ask questions containing some *keywords* that trigger reviewers to close them as off-topic: "GPIO", "baud rate", "reboot", "HW flow control" and so on. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65032398/11336762): OP tried to reboot the device with a command, they didn't succeed, so they asked for the correct command to be provided.

In my opinion such a question seems legitimate, as it's not relevant that the question asked about a reboot instead of the commands required to send data through [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol): they both ask for AT commands *doing something*. So, since I've some knowledge of the topic, I voted for reopening it and I tried to help the OP providing the solution in a comment.

**But maybe I'm wrong**. So I ask: is, in general, the *at-commands* tag on topic on Stack Overflow, even when asking something not directly related to a C program or a Python script? If yes, I'll accept the verdict and I'll simply stop following the tag and I won't "fight" anymore for reopening closed questions<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)</sup>.

But, if these questions are "legal", what can I do to improve the management of these *borderline* questions?

---

<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)</sup> These fights are rarely successful, anyway, as it is very difficult to get a question reopened. And, to be honest, this is a so *low traffic tag* that even obtaining the closure of a question that blatantly deserve it is really difficult (an example: once a user opened exactly the same question, with the same words, in a couple days. Unfortunately my closure flag timed out).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on how sending these command is actually a programming problem or a task commonly faced by programmers? Why wouldn't these questions fly on Super User?

Comment: Syntax problems with AT commands are comparable with syntax problems with command-line parameters (say, for [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) - `-mtime` comes to mind (rounding to nearest day (off by one problem) and direction (older/younger))). Is using piped commands on the command line (e.g. `find`, `grep`, `xargs`, `head`, `tail`, and `perl`) a form of programming?

Comment: The association might be with ancient history, but AT commands are not only for modems. They are also used for talking with embedded Wi-Fi systems, like [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266).

Comment: @rene I am not sure what the destination of this tag would be (that's why I'm genuinely asking it), but it won't be super user. These are commands provided to external devices through serial port, and not administrative commands provided through a command shell. Though you can theoretically providing them by opening a terminal, the final goal will always be a program performing actions _programmatically_. E.g. an embedded application collecting data in a crop field through a network of sensors might send these data to a server with a cellular modem connected to the host processor.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm the asker and I'm open to see what the community opinion will be. Anyway,IMHO that is a form of programming or,at least,a side topic a programmer could deal with. Some other examples: 1) _"is TCP a form of programming?"_ No, but programmers have often to deal with it (21k questions). - 2) _"Are Git questions about programming?"_ No,but it is an essential tool for programmers (128k questions) - 3) _"Are Arduino questions about programming?"_ Well,yes,but they often imply a deep knowledge of the involved HW,and sometimes are more about tools than about the code snippets (16k)

Comment: I was under the impression that this tag was about the at command present in *nix systems and part of cron. You sure this tag is about that at?

Comment: @Braiam yes I am. You're not the first falling in this pit. The correct tag for `at`... cron-related command is [at-utility]. (I "correct" the tag whenever I find that the wrong one is used).

Comment: That seems like a shore that can be avoided by disambiguation. at command heavily implies that it's a shell command rather than the Hayes thing.

Comment: Maybe the Hayes thing should be named something like `modem-at-command` (@PeterMortensen yes, I read what you said, but this is what it's most associated with).

Comment: @Barmar `modem-at-command` would be ok; anyway [pedantic]Hayes commands are just a subset of all the AT commands set; more precisely those like `ATD`. `ATH` and so on[/pedantic]

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735154/overload-and-error-differentiation-by-can-controller) of a conceptual-only question for another protocol ([CAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Yes

Wow, it's been a long time since I've thought of [AT commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set).

I believe you've successfully made the case that [at-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-command) has relevance to programmers and is on-topic on Stack Overflow.  I leave this answer as a voting conduit for those who agree with you that [at-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-command) questions are fine.

Hopefully you'll receive a substantial enough consensus affirming your argument to keep [at-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-command) that you'll be able to reference this Q/A in the future when such questions are challenged.  Thanks for your answers and moderation in this niche tag.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? What if [the answer depends on the characteristics of some hardware device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019177/sim7600-send-sms-from-a-roaming-sim-card) (for instance, its implementation of the AT protocol, timing, etc.), not the code per se?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: IMO, code robustness across devices is fair game.  If in some particular case the answer is that the AT standard is poorly implemented (or misunderstood or ambiguous) in a particular device or category of devices, that's useful and could reasonably be expected to help future readers as well as OP.

Comment: The AT commands can also be on topic when they're implemented as part of the program you're working on. For example, this [Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954123/how-to-send-and-receive-some-data-via-a-gsm-modem-during-an-active-call-python) dealing with the modem directly. [Cellular modems](https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/at-commands-gsm-at-command-set/) can also use AT commands to send SMS/MMS, etc...Having  hardware send messages is a common programming problem. For example, when you're trying to get every van in the fleet to send an SMS periodically.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Just like questions about dealing with Internet Explorer's poor or non-existent support for DOM standards are on-topic (if, thankfully, now very rare as IE is ever-so-nearly dead). But IMHO it was smart of you to raise that question here.

Comment: I think whoever DV'd should post an answer that begins **NO**.  Agreed that AT commands are completely on topic.

Comment: AT-commands are the protocol by which many many mobile devices communicate between their app code and their telephony subsystems. AT-commands are not obsolete, even though the old [Heatherington '302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Independent_Escape_Sequence) patent assigned to Hayes expired in 2003.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is of course the answer I hoped for, but I'll wait some days before accepting it, in order to give some time to the different opinion stated in the other answer. PS: in the meanwhile the _meta effect_ caused the question to be reopened so, pinged by @T.J.Crowder, I expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, every manner of data communication protocol is on-topic here. This is because these mainly sort under the branch of software engineering, far more so than electrical engineering. You can't really have any form of higher layer data communication without software on both sides of the transmission. Relevant data communication topics such as payload, checksums and endianess also sort under software engineering.

AT commands is a crude application layer on top of UART etc. The application layer in particular is on-topic here. Questions about the hardware layer is better asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. The EE site generally accepts all manner of data communication questions though, from hardware to application layers, so there is a scope overlap between the sites.

The problems with AT commands specifically, is that they aren't standardized, so every device will have its whole set of them. Generally, questions regarding how a specific device works aren't suitable for this site. I think the example you gave was such a question - it isn't really about programming or software engineering, so Super User might have been a more suitable site for it, though I'd ask their meta before posting/migrating such questions there.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. You write _"The problems with AT commands specifically, is that they aren't standardized"_... yes they are. [Hayes AT commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) (both base commands such as `ATD` or `ATH` and extended "ampersen" command such as `AT&W` or `AT&P`) are actually a standard and, on cellular modems are supported by a specific set (one example is [ETSI TS 127.007](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/15.03.00_60/ts_127007v150300p.pdf)).

Comment: Then, of course, every vendor (Quectel, Telit, Sierra, Gemalto and so on) supports their specific extension for performing special actions (for example: sockets support or services such as HTTP, FTP...) but once you know a vendor you can easily approach another one. IMHO it is not so different to SQL vs. SQL dialects (though it is an extreme example of something that many programmer consider an essential part of their knowledge).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni In the context of traditional modems where you expect to find them, they might be standardized. But almost every embedded Bluetooth, Wifi etc stand-alone radio module out there likes to use these too, each in their own custom manner.