# Good question etiquette for generalising questions regarding a protocol, not a framework or language

Tags: discussion, questions

### ***TLDR***

A `protocol` can be used by many languages and frameworks - their usage is fundamentally generalised to some extent.

If the key part of the question is not regarding the development of the protocol itself, can questions about implementations using a protocol be generalised to improve answer availability?

Meta question: *When should a question be generalised?*

---

I'm new to SO and considering how best to draft a question about an implementation of the [Open Sound Control](http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc) (OSC) protocol in a project I'm working on. One way to ask the question might be to talk about it from the perspective of the language (Swift) and the specific OSC library I'm using in order to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, the question I'm asking relates more to guidance in testing and debugging systems that use the OSC protocol itself and may get better quality answers in being more generalised. The documentation itself doesn't give great insight into implementations of sync with OSC bundles for instance, where examples from developers showing their approaches would be very valuable for learning.

For instance, I'd like to know how to test synchronisation methods and measure drift in OSC systems, which relate closely to the schedulers being used - in my case schedulers in Swift. However, there are likely to be some heuristics/methods for implementing sync and drift measurements when using an OSC implementation in other (more common) languages like C or C++ which I could learn from and port into my implementation.

In searching, I haven't found these answers on SO, so in developing the question I have considered writing an example in C++ in order to get more attention to my question. In the outcome that a comment or answer from another framework or language leads to a new or more robust implementation in my specific case - this would be supplied and recorded as an answer for others to find also. However, this feels perhaps against the intentions of the SO question/answer design model?

My understanding is that SO is designed to focus toward specialised questions in order to better deliver specialised answers. However, I've found that works differently when searching for questions regarding say a protocol rather than a language or framework, in that they can be deployed in many different languages/frameworks.
Rather than getting my question downvoted, edited or closed - I'm hoping someone from meta might provide some insight on best practice here.

Comment: What would a good answer to your proposed question look like?

Comment: "I haven't done this in Swift, but when I do this in C++ this is how I do it" - isn't that against SO guidelines though? That's what I'm trying to understand

Comment: So you're looking for Swift specific idioms as they apply to a particular protocol, using some prototypical C++ code as a starting point?

Comment: No, I'm looking for language agnostic _protocol_ specific idioms, if you get me, C++ is just an example - but yes the target is Swift ultimately.

Comment: OK.  Forget for a moment about how to ask it, and just tell us what is the actual question you want to ask.

Comment: I have long document itis, so can you put include a draft of the question in this question?

Comment: "How to measure and correct sync and drift between OSC packets and a playing media file (audio) from an IOS device to a wireless LAN connected device" tags: Swift, Openframeworks, C++

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  Do you have any attempt at writing code to solve the problem?

Comment: Though I suspect the short answer to the question is "buffering and time-tagging."

Comment: Yes, I could add it here - but from the sounds of it I should just put it up on SO

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yes, I've spent days searching for good documentation regarding buffering and time tagging and not getting anywhere.

Comment: The question I'd really like to ask is, "How do you implement buffering and timetagging to synchronise OSC messages with media files" which is much more agnostic..

Comment: Add a buffer, time-tag all of your packets, match everything up.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: yes, but the simplicity is deceptive, "match everything up" when two schedulers are involved has been very difficult in this project. I'm seeking guidance.

Comment: Ah, now we're narrowing down to a specific problem.  The better you can articulate the specific problem you're having, the more likely it is to be accepted on Stack Overflow.  And it does sound like you've put some effort into your problem.  Post the code you have, describe the specific problems you're having, and ask for guidance to solve those specific problems.

Comment: Related (also about a protocol): *[Are questions about \[at-command\]s on-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403258)*

Comment: This meta question appears to lack a **question** 

Comment: @DimaTisnek added a TLDR that summarises the question

Comment: So you are looking for *experts in `[osc]`* to help you? What would a *`[C++]`* expert that doesn't know a thing about OSC have to offer you? Sounds like your question would just make them loose their time. If you think your  question could have specifics because of the language you are using, then explain clearly in the question your situation. If an OSC expert that doesn't know a thing about Swift answers that it's dependent on the language and you have to check how schedulers work in Swift, then open a new `[swift]` question about schedulers.

Comment: Yep, that gets to the heart of the question here - if the question isn't general then it necessitates posting further questions  - so according to meta, many specific questions are better than a central generalised question, correct? That's what I'm clarifying.

Comment: @lys "many specific questions are better than a central generalised question" is correct in the sense of that is how Stack Overflow is designed to work. In contrast, your "central generalised question" would end up being very broad and thus likely to attract broad answers, which is the opposite of how SO is designed to work. My suggestion is to break this general question down into multiple **specific** questions, ask them, and link them together by, quite literally, placing links to the other questions in each question's body.

Comment: @lys You must remember, what you're wanting to ask about is very much the exception to the rule - most questions here are simple once-offs with no follow-ups (often a user account will only ever ask a single question), hence Stack Overflow's software and rules are designed towards facilitating that common case and not your more overarching one. That is not to say you should not be asking about big, general problems - only that in order to do so, you need to tailor how you ask about those problems, to the way the site is designed to operate. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @lys And don't be worried about asking "too many" questions - the quality of the question is all that counts. If your questions are as well-researched and thoughtful as this Meta one is, PLEASE FOR ALL THAT IS HOLY ask as many as possible.... it will be a lovely change from the hordes of terrible questions that we see on a daily basis.

Comment: Another protocol-related meta question: *[Is there a specific Stack Exchange site for asking information regarding radio, their protocols, implementation in code, etc.?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357757)*

Comment: Thanks Ian, though it seems many people want short questions that don’t really demonstrate the research and consideration going into the question either - (“long document-itis” , requests for tldrs, edits pushing tldr to top of question) which seems pretty redundant for a well voted questions without a single answer ‍♂️