# Synonym proposal [opensoundcontrol] -> [osc]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Currently two tags are being used for the [Open Sound Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) protocol.

- [osc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osc) - 229 questions.
- [opensoundcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensoundcontrol) - 12 questions ([only 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensoundcontrol+-osc) are not also tagged [osc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osc)).

They both have the same exact excerpt and share a good portion of their wiki.

I suggest that [opensoundcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensoundcontrol) be made a synonym of [osc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osc).

Comment: Would you object to making [[tag:opensoundcontrol]] the "main" tag? Or is the library more commonly known by its initialism, OSC?

Comment: I am not myself an expert in this domain at all, but back in the days I was playing with sound, I definitely saw more the acronym than the full spelled-out name. Even looking at the wikipedia article, they only use the full name only in the first sentence. I believe it's more common to use "OSC" than "opensourcecontrol", much like HTTP for instance, and the number of questions on both tags would also indicate that. But I personally have no objection using the full name instead, I can see how acronyms make for more ambiguous tag names.

Comment: Yeah, OK. That pretty much answers my question. Only other thing to think about is whether "OSC" is actually creating collisions. I assume not, given that that's been the primary spelling of the tag on SO for quite some time. Going to leave this up for a bit to let anyone who has thoughts weigh in.

Comment: @CodyGray There are other things using the same abbreviation (although opensoundcontrol is the most prevalant one): online study center, open science center, online service center, olympic sports club, but also an [SAP consulting firm](https://www.osc-ag.info), the [Open Suse Commander](https://github.com/openSUSE/osc) or the [Open Stage Control](https://github.com/jean-emmanuel/open-stage-control/) project which might be on topic

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind when hearing "osc" is "oscillation/oscillator" (like in "3OSC"). But apparently, OSC (Open Sound Control) can generate OSC (oscillator)?

Comment: @Bergi Just to be confusing, Open Stage Control refers to itself as an "*...OSC/MIDI controller*". Although that does emphasise the ubiquity of the OSC acronym for open sound control.

Comment: Also about Open Sound Control: *[Good question etiquette for generalising questions regarding a protocol, not a framework or language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403528)*

Comment: @Andrew T.: In slightly different contexts, "osc" is a shorthand for [oscilloscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope) (though "scope" is more common).

Comment: @AndrewT. not so much generate them, but certainly control their parameters. It's widely accepted to refer to the sound generation components of the almost all audio synthesis architectures as OSCs in both the digital and analogue world - much more common than people using the CNMAT protocol. It's even more confusing since sound is only one application of the OSC protocol - it's really useful for all sorts of other things