# Question is on-topic for one site, but fits userbase knowledge of another where it would be off-topic

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-crossover

I very recently asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1635104/zmodem-crashing-with-large-files-over-tcp) over on Super User about [ZMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM). This is fairly old technology and from what I've seen from browsing this site, it's something that a good few Stack Overflow users are quite knowledgeable about.

However, due to how I'm implementing it, I can't really frame my problem as a programming question, making Super User the appropriate site to ask, which makes me fear I won't get an answer, even if I later bounty it; Super User doesn't even have a `zmodem` tag and questions on the protocol are few, far between, and low activity.

Is there anything I can do in this situation, or have I done all that is appropriate?

Comment: Maybe checkout chat, specially if retrocomputing.se has an active room. The question itself sounds "too localized" although that is a close reason that is long gone now. It was used on questions where the answer probably only helps you and not many more users.

Comment: Related (also about protocols, not necessarily duplicate): *[Are questions about \[at-command\]s on-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403258)* and *[Burninate \[electronics\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404730)*

Comment: Those ancient protocols are still being used as fallbacks, when resource constrained, etc. for new products (because they are so simple to implement).

Comment: @PeterMortensen in this case I believed the question was off topic for SO not because of the specific protocol, but because the implementation I'm using (and the general context I'm using it in) can't reasonably be called 'programming'

Comment: If it's about using a tool, it should go on Super User.  If it's about programming a tool, or using a tool for programming, it should go on Stack Overflow.  Yes, more Stack Overflow users might know about the technology you are using, but if they wanted to answer questions on how to use tools, they would look on Super User.  If they're looking on Stack Overflow, they want to answer questions about programming.  My point: posting on the wrong site will never help you.  Note: I have no knowledge of ZMODEM, so you will have to figure out how this applies to your situation.

Comment: The fact that a lot of StackOverflow users might know the answer does not make it on topic. (I imagine that a lot of StackOverflow users know about cat feeding, but that doesn't mean you should ask questions about cats here.)  Ask questions on the site where they are on-topic. (IMO, you have done the right thing by NOT posting it to StackOverflow.)

Comment: If you think your question is more about hardware not working satisfactorily, it might be ontopic on electronics.stackexchange. Their ask page mention communication schemes as ontopic.

Comment: @StephenC though i think a lot of SO users would have trouble keeping a plant alive, let alone a cat

Comment: @TheGeneral considering that the cat will feed itself if not fed, the plant is harder.

Comment: @StephenC FWIW about a year ago company attempted to bridge the gap with ["integration experiment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396370/839601). Back then they failed miserably, although this probably was because implementation was extremely awkward... softly speaking. Maybe general idea per se still has some merit

Comment: Not every question is going to be answered. I am sorry if you don't get an answer on super user because none of SO zmodem experts are there. You may try your luck at SO (but don't) asking offtopic question (so don't) and hoping for some helpful comments (not answer) at the cost of downvotes and risk of getting bans. But rather you should use your internet points at super user to pay bounty and get the answer there.

Comment: @StephenC, so let me get this straight, we're supposed to ask question on a site that doesn't likely have people who would know the answer because asking where the people with the correct knowledge and interest is "off-topic"? That sounds like the exact opposite of the intelligence these Stacks are supposed to encourage. Sounds like there needs to be a way to cross-post without things being closed as "off-topic" with the specific purpose to get more attention to a Question. And a bounty doesn't do that.

Comment: @computercarguy: yeah, it's kind of an unsolved problem.  I don't want to monitor multiple other SEs for questions of the sort I want to answer (a smaller set than those where I know the answer), so I tend to only see outside of SO itself via hot network questions.  (e.g. performance / cpu-architecture / SIMD / asm stuff on electornics.SE or codereview.SE, or sometimes CPU-architecture stuff on superuser).  Or when searching for something else, sometimes I come across a years-old on another site that's worth an answer, but that's not great for the original asker.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it seems as if there is at least a partial solution, if unwieldy. The "integration experiment" gnat talks about seems like a good start, but maybe needs to be moved under "Linked" and "Related" and above "HNQ"? It might take some time to get it working well, but at least it wouldn't be as obnoxious. Members could simply subscribe to/watch tags from other stacks that could more easily show their interests in that area? It could also pull from frequently Answered tags for the member. That way content is funneled to people in a more cultivated way, instead of randomly, like HNQ.

Comment: I have 113 separate stackexchange network accounts by now, but still stackoverflow.com is my landing page almost every time. And almost every time the shown questions on SO aren't really interesting. Discovery of interesting unanswered questions is really a big problem. It's not your fault that your question will likely not be seen and answered. If only I had a better way to express what interests I have network wide.

Comment: The only appropriate thing left for you to try is the bounty.

Comment: @Trilarion What's stopping you from making https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime your landing page? Every site has a defined target audience for good reason. If I start seeing "English" questions on the front page of Stack Overflow because someone figured a lot of English speakers are using Stack Overflow then I will throw a fit.

Comment: I don't really understand why people are making comparisons to things like feeding cats and using English.

Comment: @holydragon, a bounty might be their only option, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate or that it will be useful, as it still won't draw the attention of people who don't visit the Stack.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I wanted interesting questions, not just all questions. And I wanted them presented on a new page taking nothing away from the experience of others. But if I could filter by stack exchanges and maybe kind of group them, I might give stackexchange.com a try.

Comment: @Trilarion Sounds like a viable feature-request for https://meta.stackexchange.com/ then. [I am aware that Stack Overflow came first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234859/235923) but it is the wrong place to request such a feature since it is a child of the parent now.

Comment: *"I don't really understand why people are making comparisons to things like feeding cats...."* - It was intended to be humorous, while also making the point that we have the notion of "off-topic" for a reason.