# How is this bountied question about cryptography in-scope?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, declined-flags

I have recently spent a lot of time flagging questions I find in the bounty tab as I've noticed a surprising number of off-topic or bad questions get bountied when no one bothers to answer them (perhaps a topic for another day).

On my crusade, I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217076/example-of-hash-collision-printable-strings).

> ## Example of hash collision (printable strings)
>
> I've searched a lot for md5 hash collision, but I've found binary examples only. I would like to find two UTF8 strings, which have the same md5 hash. Are there any, or the collision works only for binary data?

I'll admit, it is an interesting question. However, to me it seems the question is more about cryptographic theory than software development.

In addition, the question is tagged [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), which makes sense. However, the tag guidance reads the following:

> CRYPTOGRAPHY MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Cryptography covers, among other things, symmetric and asymmetric encryption, hashing, and digital signatures. **Cryptography questions not directly related to software development are better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com.**

This further cements my reasoning for this question being off-topic. This question should be asked on [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com). Thus, I raised a custom flag (because bountied questions cannot be flagged normally) with the message

> This question is off topic, but has a bounty.

However, my flag was declined with the message

> I see no reason why this is off-topic. Not a programming question? You must surely be joking!

Screenshot:

[image: A declined flag for the question linked above reading: "This question is off topic, but has a bounty – spicy.dll 21 hours ago declined - I see no reason why this is off-topic. Not a programming question? You must surely be joking!"]

I get that determining what's on topic on Stack Overflow can be very subjective. However, what confuses me is how confident this moderator is on how this question is on topic. Confident to the point of asking if I'm pulling some prank by flagging this question.

In hindsight, my custom flag could have been more detailed with why I thought the question is off topic. However, I figured it was pretty obvious that this question did not directly relate to software development and was rather about cryptographic theory.

I reflagged the question after OP opened another bounty on it. I did this because I felt a majority of people responding to this meta question agreed that it's off-topic. It has since been closed. It is under review for reopening.

Is this question on topic for the site? If so, why?

Comment: So you think the question is in no way whatsoever programming related?

Comment: @JeanneDark It's not **directly** programming related. Yes, you may need to consider the possibility of hash collisions while developing software, but this question is not formed in this context.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with "my custom flag could have been more detailed with why I thought the question is off topic". At first sight, it looks a poorly-written, poorly-researched, but on-topic question.

Comment: It might also have been useful to mention in the flag text why such an old question needed to be closed immediately and you couldn't wait to flag it normally after the bounty ended. No moderator involvement was necessary.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree and I will definitely at a minimum give a brief description of my reasoning from now on. However, I do not feel like this question is so indisputably on topic to warrant a flag reviewer to ask if I'm joking.

Comment: @JeanneDark That's certainly fair. I honestly didn't notice how old the question was when I flagged it. I have been focusing on bountied questions mainly because I felt that these are questions that newer users would see first to get an impression of what questions are good. I felt that having off topic or badly formed questions in the bounty tab reinforces that these questions are ok. Maybe my "bounty crusade" efforts are misplaced...

Comment: eh, well, the issue is mods are unlikely to take action if the bounty has been up for more than a day, for fear of giving the user that day of advertising for free. (regardless of the fact that the whole point is to remove content that shouldn't be there anyway)

Comment: In this case, because the question and a few answers are upvoted, there's little chance it'll get removed regardless of whether or not it's on topic.

Comment: @KevinB Good to know. It would have been more useful to me if the decline message represented this fact, however. The message indicated to me that this flag was declined due to the question actually being on topic, rather than not worth their time.

Comment: All of the advice you've gotten in comments is good, and you should follow it, but none of it contributed to the flag being declined in this specific case.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out how that question is related to programming or belongs on SO.

Comment: If a bountied question is "closed" is the bounty refunded?! "bountied questions cannot be flagged normally" - Can't they? Is this a rep-thing? (It looks pretty _normal_ to me?) ... although I would refrain from flagging _bountied_ questions to begin with.

Comment: @CodyGray Could you explain your reasoning behind why you think this question is on topic so I can see where you're coming from?

Comment: I've voted to close the question once the bounty expired.  Within 1 minute of my close vote, OP had added a new bounty for +200 rep.  I've flagged this again for moderator attention as this question does not belong on SO.

Comment: Based on the title I was expecting to disagree, but you actually convinced me. What’s more, the moderator (?) response to the flag was incredibly poor, and I’ve noticed this happen to several of my declined flags as well. Maybe this merits its own question: response to declined yet reasonable flags is dismissive to the point of being outright rude and it causes me to use flags a lot less than I used to.

Comment: I cannot understand why people think it's on topic. It doesn't even specify a programming language, and provides no code. That question should be closed with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera "extreme prejudice"? Really? It's not a Question about knitting a sweater. And about the no code: Not all Questions need code.

Comment: Heh, that was just for effect. This specific question is not asking anything programming related: the OP does have an answer to their question about examples of hash collisions. But they want them as UTF8 strings: that's different, ie., "how do I convert this binary data to UTF8?", which is now clearly a programming question (and one that would be promptly closed without code, I might add).

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera The OP is not asking for converting the known colliding binary strings to UTF-8 (which is bogus – binary is UTF-8 or it is not). They are asking for people to just *list examples* of UTF-8 data that has collisions – that's the issue, listing examples is not a programming issue.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see your point. Then I'm even more confused why people think that is programming related.

Comment: [Protocol questions without any code whatsoever are on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403258). Perhaps this is similar? - perhaps some analogies can be drawn?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I would argue this is distinct from being a protocol question. The meta question you linked is talking about [tag:at-commands], which is an API for programmers. While it's technically not code that would execute, it's definitely a language that's interpreted by a machine. The question I've disputed is essentially about data that has a certain property. This question is similar to asking "What are two numbers that mod to the same value." This isn't a software development problem, it's a theoretical numbers problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The linked question seems reasonably on-topic to me, but I don't have strong feelings about it either way. Regardless, if you do feel that the question is off-topic, you really should be more explicit in your flag (as you seem to be aware already). The reasons stated in this question would work; "it's not really about software", etc.

Also, while the action you would like to be taken is implicit, it doesn't hurt to say what that action is, in the flag text. Something like "... so the question should be closed." would work fine.

It's also not clear why moderator intervention is required at all. At the time of your raising the flag, the bounty was due to expire in a couple of days. You could just wait for the period to end, and then cast a close vote/flag it yourself, without needing a moderator to get involved. If the bounty was raised recently, then it might make sense to ask for moderator intervention.

That being said, a large part of the reason you posted this meta question appears to be the wording of the decline message. I do agree that it's poorly worded; it implies that you raised the flag in bad faith, or that it was a completely misguided flag. *Even* if that's true, IMO it's not productive to say that in the decline message. Simply declining with just the first sentence of the message, or even the canned "no evidence to support the flag" would have been sufficient. Don't worry about it too much; raise more detailed flags in the future, and you're unlikely to get responses like that (whether the flag is declined, or not).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have gone through my pending flags and retracted the ones flagged for mods due to bounties (most of the bounties expired already anyway). In the future, I will wait to flag until the bounty expires unless the question is worth bugging the mods for without the bounty. Although I feel questions that are to be bountied should go through a review queue or something to ensure low quality questions don't get advertised. I feel like the damage has been done once the bounty expires.

Comment: I absolutely thought the flag was raised in bad faith. There is no doubt in my mind that the flagged question was on-topic.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, that's certainly what the phrasing implied. As mentioned in my answer, it's not clear to me what benefit there is to saying that in the decline message. Anyway, is the advice in the answer any good? i.e. if there were more details in the flag message, would it have looked to you like it was raised in good faith?

Comment: This is interesting, as to me the question seems in no way to be programming related.  It's not asking for how one would determine this programmatically nor does it include or ask for any code examples nor is it presented in any software development context, neither does it include any programming language to be used for any such examples.  To me it seems like it belongs in crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @spicy.dll Please flag off-topic questions with bounties. They should be flagged. There's a bit of a backlog of custom flags at the moment, but hopefully that will be resolved. Mods do, sometimes, skim through the recently raised ones to handle easy/time sensitive things, which a flag for removing a bounty usually is. We'd prefer to get a flag early in the bounty cycle; prior to an answer being posted is definitely better. There are trade-offs with handling such questions, so the choice *may* be to let the bounty run, but often it's better to refund the bounty and close.

Comment: This question is all about the abstract/academic/theoretical foundation. That's in no way of form a **practical** question about programming. Once you figure out those issues, then you can move to the implementation step.