# What is the recommended way of dealing with old (then on-topic) question with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, downvotes, old-questions

I posted [a question about MD5 hash collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217076/example-of-hash-collision-printable-strings) back in 2014. As far as I know questions about algorithms are on-topic on Stack Overflow, and the cryptography tag did not have the warning "CRYPTOGRAPHY MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED" back then. The question is not phrased the best, but it got reasonable answers, and no negative feedback.

I recently came across this old question, and it did not have an answer and so many years have passed, I decided to start a bounty on it, to get more up to date answers.

Someone reported it for being off-topic, but a mod declined it with a comment "I see no reason why this is off-topic. Not a programming question? You must surely be joking!", so it seems that this is controversial for the mods as well.

They opened [a question here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412595/how-is-this-bountied-question-about-cryptography-in-scope), and suddenly my question got 25 downvotes, and eventually got closed for being off-topic. I do understand why some of you decided to close it, but in my opinion it could have been more constructive to move this question to cryptography stack exchange, instead of downvoting and closing it.

Stack Overflow is full of old "not directly programming related" cryptography questions, that are highly upvoted. Those have to be closed/locked as well? Just to name a few:

- [Is it possible to decrypt MD5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)
- [Is calculating an MD5 hash less CPU intensive than SHA family functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943/is-calculating-an-md5-hash-less-cpu-intensive-than-sha-family-functions)
- [What's the shortest pair of strings that causes an MD5 collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999824/whats-the-shortest-pair-of-strings-that-causes-an-md5-collision?lq=1)
- [Maximum length for MD5 input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394503/maximum-length-for-md5-input-output)

What is the recommended policy in this case? How is it possible to request to move the question to cryptography stack exchange? Should I update the question to be more programming related, by asking about how to generate such strings?

Comment: "*it could have been more constructive to move this question to cryptography stack exchange*" the question is too old to migrate.

Comment: @VLAZ What is the reason for that rule in this case?

Comment: The rule applies in all cases. It is impossible to migrate questions that are more than 60 days old, even for moderators. Therefore, I recommend choosing the latter option of updating your question to be more explicitly programming-related.

Comment: Welcome to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)! Did you like it? Just to be clear upfront: Some visitors of this question might not be able to resist the urge to cast their votes as well. It is an unfortunate *c'est la vie* ... :(

Comment: @rene Thanks, I updated the question title. I am not mad about the "meta effect" and the downvoting, as long as I get constructive comments as well

Comment: "..my question got 25 downvotes.." Sounds excessive at first glance, but then the question merely ended up at a score of -4 and a net reputation gain, so not the worst outcome. "How is it possible to request to move the question to cryptography stack exchange?.." One way to move one of your questions yourself would be to recreate at target site (check for potential duplicates before) and then delete here. That's what I would recommend. Being offtopic doesn't equal not useful. It might be very useful at a more appropriate site. "Those have to be closed/locked as well?" Sure.

Comment: _"Stack Overflow is full of old <subject> questions, that are highly upvoted. Those have to be closed/locked as well?"_ That doesn't mean that they're on-topic now. If someone were to bounty one of those, it might just as well be closed, as something that's bountied _now_ should be up to current standards.

Comment: There's a way to migrate to cryto.se, ask the same question there. Note, you need to make sure that it's accepted there too.

Answer (score -3):

For me, the question's problem is that it entirely lacks context. Why exactly do you want to know these duplicate hashes? How does knowing these dupes help anything or anyone? **What, exactly, is the use of this question to future readers?**

This lack of context applies to any Stack Exchange site, so posting the question as-is to cryptography.se would likely result in its closure there too.

Lacking context, your request for these duplicate hashes reads like something that a search engine would be better equipped to answer, which is why I voted to close said question as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". That's not entirely the same, but it's the closest reason I can find.

As for the custom close reason: the question is technically programming-related because MD5 falls within the domain of programming, but doesn't require any knowledge of programming to answer: it's just asking for hashes that collide. Someone who is an expert on cryptography, but has never written a line of code, could likely answer it. I don't agree with this close reason, hence why I picked the one I mentioned above, but I can understand said reasoning from a theoretical viewpoint.

> Should I update the question to be more programming related, by asking about how to generate such strings?

That still doesn't answer the question of **why** you want these strings.

Comment: I don't think adding context to his question would make it in-scope. In fact, I don't think the question can be in scope without changing the entire premise. It's just a cryptography problem. I also think (barring duplicate checking) his question could be asked as is on [crypto.se] and follow all their post rules.

Comment: @spicy.dll adding more context in the way of "how is this programming related". Pure crypto problems aren't within the scope of SO. All questions are supposed to be "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: It seems more like a curiosity question than anything else, but in any case, it definitely has nothing to do with programming -- it is literally just asking for example printable UTF-8 strings that have the same MD5 hash. That would be like saying a question that asks for two different images that have the same histogram was about programming because images are also used in programming.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest there should be an informal "statute of limitations" where moderators are more cautious changing questions or answers over five years old. This could be facilitated by migration to a more relevant community. It might also be supported by some metadata, such as a tag.

Sites and communities evolve, and it is an impossible task to constantly rewrite old content according to new understandings of social conventions.

Old information is useful information when the context that it is historical is maintained. Imagine a user of Stack Overflow in five years time, who has some reason to wrangle with a language or library from 2011. The specific technical answers, and even the question itself, will give insight on how to deal with it.

Lastly there is some social sense that it is more unfair to "punish" a poster for something that was conventional at the time. It would be good to avoid that. (And indeed, my advocacy of preservation over removal echoes other contemporary social debates today. Hopefully we can separate the technical history being discussed here from more fraught topics.)

One way to help coordinate could be a "legacy-non-programming" tag. However it is mostly for editorial and moderator use, and tags are added by general users, I'm not sure if it's quite the right mechanism.

Comment: If how to treat history has been done to death before, links to those discussions appreciated.